# Not getting how the property rotation works in SceneKit

Tags: objective-c, scenekit

When you specify a rotation for an object, you do something like this :

```
_earthNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, M_PI/2);
```

What I am not getting is how to specify a specific rotation for each axis ? Because let's say that I wanted to rotate my node from PI on x, PI/2 on y, and PI/4 on z, how would I do that ? I thought that I could do something like this :

```
_earthNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0.5, 0.25, M_PI);
```

But it doesn't change anything....
**How does this property works ?**

Answer (score 3):

The rotation vector in Scene Kit is specified as the axis of rotation (first 3 components) follow by the angle (4th component), called [axis-angle representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation).

[image]

The format you are trying to specify (the different angles along each axis) is called [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) (unless I'm remembering wrong).

---

Translating between the two representations is just a bit of trigonometry. A quick online search for "Euler angles to axis angle" lead to [this page](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToAngle/index.htm) which shows who to do it in Java.

Answer (score 2):

`SCNNode` has an `eulerAngles` property that allows you to do just that

Comment: Ah, some new 10.10 additions. Nice!